# Visual Studio Code doctrings not showing

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Python in Visual Studio Code, when I am inside parentheses after a function, Visual Studio Code shows only available function signatures. No doctstrings are shown, although this used to be the case. I have searched Internet and stack overflow to no avail (found things, but not helpful). This problem occurs both in Jupyter notebooks and .py scripts. I have Python and Pylance extensions installed.

I've tried both hovering over the code and pressing ctrl + I within parentheses. Ctrl+k also did not work for me.

How can I recover the appearance of doctrings for dynamic/quick info, short of reinstalling VS Code?

Versions:
VS Code 1.74.2
Python extension v2022.20.1
Pylance extension v2023.1.10

Answer (score 0):

I disabled and reenabled the Python extension. Disabling disabled both Python and Pylance extensions, and reenabling reenabled both; so I'm not sure if culprit was Python or Pylance extension. In any case, docstrings are showing now.